# Enumerator missing in JSON class

Tags: c#, json, enumerator

I'm trying to deserialize this [json](http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/19). But I've several problem, in particular the compiler tells me that:

> the RootObject not contains a public definition for GetEnumerator.

This is the class generated with [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/):

```
 public class Self
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fixtures
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Players
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links
    {
        public Self self { get; set; }
        public Fixtures fixtures { get; set; }
        public Players players { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string code { get; set; }
        public string shortName { get; set; }
        public string squadMarketValue { get; set; }
        public string crestUrl { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my code:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseText);

            foreach (var item in obj)
            {
                item.name //... this is an example of the attribute that I want grab from the JSON for each team    
            }
```

I need to iterate over all the teams and save them into a database.

Here is the structure of the JSON, if it can be of any help:

```
{
"_links":{
"self":{
"href":"http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/19"
},
"fixtures":{
"href":"http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/19/fixtures"
},
"players":{
"href":"http://api.football-data.org/alpha/teams/19/players"
}
},
"name":"Eintracht Frankfurt",
"code":"SGE",
"shortName":"Eintr. Frankfurt",
"squadMarketValue":"69,050,000 €",
"crestUrl":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Eintracht_Frankfurt_Logo.svg"
}
```

Comment: The message is quite clear, your object isn't enumerable.

Comment: It's _one_ object. What do you expect that `foreach()` to do exactly? You can use `obj.name` if you want to read the name. It only contains one name.

Comment: Can you show me please how iterate this json from grab all value? I want get (link, name, code, shortname, squadMarketValue, crestUrl) for each team.

Comment: @HaroldFinch your json represents only one team. You haven't posted how you get that json, so it's impossible to help. Are you making an HTTP call or reading it from a database? Are you calling some API? Did you check the documentation to see how to get data for many teams? We can't even guess how to do such things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseText);
```

will return one single RootObject and not a collection of objects.

I think the problem lies in your api call. You are making a request that returns one single team (Eintracht Frankfurt) in this case.

You want to make a call that returns a list of teams instead.